# Why is the charge of an electron defined as a percentage of itself?

Tags: electrons, coulombs-law

An electron is usually defined to have a charge of 1.602 × 10-19 coulombs. But a Coulomb is the amount of electrons accumulated in 1 second = 6.24 x 10^18 charge carriers. An electron charge is defined in terms of a percentage of the number of electrons accumulated in 1 second?

Isn't it a bit useless to define it as such?

Comment: The Coulomb is defined by stating that the charge of the electron is **exactly** $1.602176634 \times 10^{-19}$C. The charge of an electron is what it is - it does not have any independent definition.

Comment: No, it is not useless.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, A coulomb (C) is the standard unit of electric charge in the International System of Units (SI). It is the amount of electricity that a 1-ampere (A) current carries in one second (s).

Comment: You can use any units you like, it all depends on what is the application and on history (electric circuits vs particle physics, etc). In natural units for example, the charge is about e=0.303 (no unit dimensions)

Comment: A current of one Ampere is a normal everyday human-understood amount of current. One second is an normal everyday human-understood amount of time. The result of one amp for one second is a huge number of electrons. While the charge of one electron is completely imperceptible to a human, one coulomb is quite noticeable.

Comment: Similarly note the problem with numbers of atoms and moles.

Comment: While @prahar is right about the modern definition of the Coulomb, it's worth noting that the original definition of the coulomb was the charge transferred by 1 amp in one second, and the amp was defined so that $\mu_0$ would be exactly $4\pi\times 10^{-7}$ H/m. With the new definition of the coulomb,  $\mu_0$ no longer has exactly this value, but it's worth keeping in mind the original definitions so one knows where these seemingly random numerical values came from like 1.602176634

Answer (score 3):

One coulomb is currently defined to be $1/(1.602176634\times 10^{-19})$ times the elementary (electron) charge. People sometimes say the elementary charge is defined to be $1.602176634\times 10^{-19}\text{ C}$, but that's really another way of stating the definition of the coulomb. The elementary charge isn't defined by us; it just is.